# Why am I running screen inside tmux

Tags: tmux

I like to work with a small number of tmux window panes to reduce clutter.

Inside each tmux pane I then run screen. This allows me to rotate the contents of one pane between different screen sessions.

I know I can create more and more panes and litter the screen, but really I just want to have a small number of panes.

e.g. I have *x* **tmux** session, each with *y* **tmux** windows, each with 3 **tmux** panes each running *n* **screen** sessions running ssh.

Is there a better tmux only way ?

Comment: `move-pane` allows you to move panes from one window to another; is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no - imagine just one pane with lots of sub panes inside it is what I'm after. So visually I only have say 3 panes, but each pane inside has 10 ssh sessions I'm managing. I could perhaps run tmux in tmux with different key bindings I guess - but screen was easier due to different config files. Sorry if this is hard to explain 8) It's a weird way to work, but it ... works.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring that each session consists of a number of *windows*, and each window can display multiple *panes* (a pane being a subdivision of a window). Each pane has a single `ssh` session, you can move them between windows (only one window is shown at a time). You can also "zoom" a pane, which temporarily replaces the current layout of a window with just the single pane.

Comment: I'm actually already using multiple sessions to different hosts, then inside each session I have 2 windows and then in each window 3 panes. Inside each pane I then have x ssh sessions. Yes I have a lot of ssh sessions.

Comment: It might help to provide a brief example of how you create this level of nesting. Specifically, it's not clear why you are using multiple `tmux` sessions rather than more windows per session.

Comment: It's visually easier to have one tmux session running each session on a different desktop. If I have tonnes of windows it's easy to lose track of. In each session I have say a 'coding' window and then a 'testing' window. In the coding window I have 3 panes, one for each bug I'm working on. Inside each pane I have 2 or 3 ssh sessions into the server where I am coding that bug. Having a few top level sessions with desktop switching between them allows me to keep things separate. Otherwise I'd go nuts trying to maintain 64 windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is my setup too. It most closely mimics the desktop concept of multiple workspaces, each with their own layout of windows, which can be underneath each other. Neither screen nor tmux alone can do it.

This works really well with the mouse support in both. You can click the tmux status bar to select a window, and you can click on a screen split to focus it.